# GCC: undefined reference to xxx

Tags: c, gcc, linker, makefile, undefined-reference

I know that have been already asked a lot of time but I can't really solve it...
so I have a `src` folder where my `main.c` source is, an `srclib` where my `lib.c` file is stored and an `include` directory where my `lib.h` file is stored. now the makefile compiles the lib correctly and put the `lib.a` file in `lib` folder. the `main.c`includes the lib like this:

```
#include "lib.h"
```

and it's compiled with `-I ../include` option, but when i compile it I get the `undefined reference to xxx` error for every function in the library

so what am I missing?

Comment: `lib.a` is a bad name for a library, name it like `libfoo.a` and add `-Llib -lfoo` link options to gcc

Comment: it's just an example, the library is libSSL. the complet compilation command is that one:
`gcc -Wall --pedantic -g -I../include -L../lib -w -L/usr/lib -lSSL s_echo.c -o ../bin/ssl_server.out`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. `-I` is for including the header files. You also need to link with the library using `-l` option.

Note: You may need to provide the *path-to-library* using `-L` option.

To quote the [online gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options)

> `-llibrary`
>
> Search the library named library when linking...... The linker searches a standard list of directories for the library, which is actually a file named `liblibrary.a`. The linker then uses this file as if it had been specified precisely by name.

---

EDIT:

To quote the remaining part of the same manual

> It makes a difference **where** in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, `foo.o -lz bar.o` searches library `z` after file `foo.o` but before `bar.o`. If `bar.o` refers to functions in `z`, those functions may not be loaded.

So, you need to put the `-l<libanme>` at the last of your compilation statement, as `s_echo.c` uses functions defined in that particular library.

Comment: Ehm... `-L` does not link libraries, it specifies a search path for libraries. `-l` links libraries.

Comment: @FUZxxl was just updating that. :-)

Comment: added `-l ../lib` but it says `cannot find ../lib`

the complete command is:
`gcc  -Wall --pedantic -g -I ../include  -w -g3 s_echo.c -o ../bin/ssl_server.out -L/usr/lib -lssl  -l../lib`

Comment: @JacopoGrassi Please take care of the naming pattern. Updated my answer.

Comment: if I put just the name of the library the result it's the same: not found

Comment: @JacopoGrassi did you try using `-L` alsongwith?

Comment: yes, now the complete command is: `gcc  -Wall --pedantic -g -I../include -L../lib -w -L/usr/lib  -lSSL s_echo.c -o ../bin/ssl_server.out`

but still giving the undefined reference error

Comment: the name is `libSSL.a`. I'm compiling from inside the `src` folder and the `lib` folder is in the parent directory